# How to upload files from linux server to SharePoint server through local PC?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I'm finding the way to up/download files from Linux to SharePoint server. I'd like to control it through my PC, as follows.

ex : (SharePoint ----> PC ----> Linux server)

I am able to connect to the Linux server and SharePoint server each through my PC but I don't know how to connect them and to transfer files between them. Is there any way to do that? Any direct or complex way to do that will be helpful. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, and authentication will be your toughest problem to solve. The best way I know of to do it would be the NPM package [spsave](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spsave).

Assuming you have Node installed and can create simple Node apps this is super-easy to use and performs great.